# Build optimal polyline

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a task to build a polyline with least amount of sections from given set of points in 2d space but all I can find is best fitting algorithm. Any suggestions please? (I don't need a solution, just a direction to a correct solution, I still want to find it myself) [image]

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I didnt try anything yet, dont know where to start. I thought it might be a graph task but Im not really good at graphs

Comment: Do the segments have to start and end at the specified points?

Comment: Finding the truly optimal solution may be more difficult than it seems at first https://www.cut-the-knot.org/ghint.shtml

Comment: @Joni No, they dont. And segments should be strictly connected between two points, you cannot go further, as it's illustrated in 9 dots problem

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a solution, here's my attempt:

```java
private static ArrayList<Point> optimize(ArrayList<Point> p) {
        ArrayList<Point> polyline = new ArrayList<Point>();
        p = sort(p);
        polyline.add(p.get(0));
        p.remove(0);
        while(!p.isEmpty()) {
            Point curr = polyline.get(polyline.size() - 1);
            int max = 0;
            int maxIndex = maxPointsIndex(p, curr);
            if(maxIndex == -1) {
                polyline.add(p.get(0));
                p.remove(0);
            } else {
                polyline.add(p.get(maxIndex));
                Point second = p.remove(maxIndex);
                p = removeBetweenPoints(p, curr, second);
            }
        }
        return polyline;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Point> removeBetweenPoints(ArrayList<Point> p, Point f, Point s) {
        ArrayList<Point> temp = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for(int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
            if(!between(f, s, p.get(i))) {
                temp.add(p.get(i));
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private static int maxPointsIndex(ArrayList<Point> p, Point curr) {
        int max = 0;
        int maxIndex = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
            int amount = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < p.size(); j++) {
                if(i != j) {
                    if(between(curr, p.get(i), p.get(j)))
                        amount++;
                }
            }
            if (amount > max) {
                max = amount;
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    } 

    private static boolean between(Point f, Point s, Point c) {
        int dxc = c.x - f.x;
        int dyc = c.y - f.y;
        int dxl = s.x - f.x;
        int dyl = s.y - f.y;
        int cross = dxc * dyl - dyc * dxl;
        if (cross != 0)
              return false;
        boolean answer;
        if (Math.abs(dxl) >= Math.abs(dyl)) {
            if(dxl > 0)
                answer = f.x <= c.x && c.x <= s.x;
            else
                answer = s.x <= c.x && c.x <= f.x;
        }
        else {
            if(dyl > 0)
                answer = f.y <= c.y && c.y <= s.y;
            else
                answer = s.y <= s.y && c.y <= f.y;
        } 
        return answer;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Point> sort(ArrayList<Point> p) {
        boolean swapped;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for(int i = 1; i < p.size(); i++) {
                if(p.get(i).x < p.get(i-1).x) {
                    swapped = true;
                    Point temp = p.get(i);
                    p.set(i, p.get(i-1));
                    p.set(i-1, temp);
                }
            }
        } while (swapped);
        return points;
    }
```

It's straightforward but pretty massive and, probably, not optimized. Input - array list of unsorted points that should lie on a polyline; output - coordinates of optimal polyline vertices; usage -

```java
ArrayList<Point> polyline = optimize(points);
```

Basically what it does is:

1. Sorts points by X value
2. Pushes first point to new array, that is empty at the beginning
3. Removes that first point from old array
4. Takes last point from new array
5. "Connects" it to all the other points
6. Finds line (second point), that includes the most amount of other points
7. Adds new found point to new array
8. Removes new found point and all the points laying on line from old array
9. Repeats the cycle from step 4.

If you have any better solutions please share with me!